# Minecraft - Can't use the new naming system

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've had multiple problems with commands all involving the new naming system. It just won't work. Only the IDs will. For example, if I were to try

> /scoreboard objectives add snow stat.mineBlock.snow Snow

That wouldn't work. But,

> /scoreboard objectives add snow stat.mineBlock.80 Snow

would work. I have no idea why, and this has stressed me so much. This won't work in 1.7.10 or the latest snapshots. Does anybody know why this won't work? Please help.

Comment: Please don't post the same question reworded. If you give it time, I'm sure your other question on this matter will get some attention. You posted the first question during low traffic hours. Please be patient.

Comment: Sorry, I'll remember this for next time ^^

Comment: It's alright- No one answered your question about posting a new question. I'm just letting you know how the site works. On that note, keep participating. ^^ All it takes is a bit of time to learn how things work.